# How to pass parameter value when request to server

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core

```
return this.http.post<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/users/LoginUser/`, { UserName, Password })
```

I try to pass parameters to the link but parameter values remain null when requests go to the server.

Comment: not enough share code in api you take request and I didnt see json format in body param . Please share more code

Comment: 'login(UserName, Password) {
        debugger;
        return this.http.post<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/users/LoginUser/`, { UserName, Password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.userSubject.next(user);
                return user;
            }));
    }'
here is angular side code

Comment: I mean code in web api. add to please question rather than comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    login(userName:string, password:string) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        var body = {
            "UserName": userName,
            "Password": password
        }
        return this.http.post<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/users/LoginUser/`, body
        ,{
            withCredentials: null,
            headers: headers,
        })
    }

.net

    [HttpPost]
        [Route("LoginUser")]
        //[EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
        public ResponseObject<User> LoginUser(User user)
        {
            UsersBLL bll = new UsersBLL();
    
            User user = bll.LoginUser(user.UserName, user.Password);
    
            string Token = Common.JwtHelper.CreateToken(user.Id.ToString(), user.Email);
    
            user.Token = Token;
    
            bll.UpdateUser(user);
    
            return SvcResponse.SuccessReponse<User>(user);
    
        }
```

Comment: Thanks its really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("LoginUser")]
    //[EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
    public ResponseObject<User> LoginUser(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        UsersBLL bll = new UsersBLL();

        User user = bll.LoginUser(UserName, Password);

        string Token = Common.JwtHelper.CreateToken(user.Id.ToString(), user.Email);

        user.Token = Token;

        bll.UpdateUser(user);

        return SvcResponse.SuccessReponse<User>(user);

    }
```

here is server side code that is in asp.net core

Comment: Add this on the question desc